# Adobe Acrobat Javascript Compatibility

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have created a Form in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC with some JavaScript code. It works fine on my machine (running Windows 10). However, when I try to run the Form on a machine with Acrobat Pro XI, I get all sorts of error messages. Functions not defined (for example toISOstring()), numbers suddenly become NaN. Any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: It is possible that the Acrobat XI installation is damaged, and that crucial parts for Acrobat JavaScript are missing or damaged.

Comment: It might be that the JS interpreter was updated.